# Unique Names - adjust script

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below script that is totalling just like i need it too if they are all the same name.
I need to adjust script so that i can have unique names as it fills the form out and emails it. (I have other fields in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns that create this total)

I tried to get it to use the Id name (which can all by qty) but couldn't make it work.

How best to adjust the script so that is pulls names qty1 - qty 9?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
}
    </script>
```

Example input field

```
  <td id="col3">
    <input class="form-control" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" name="qty1" id="qty" readonly/><br>
  </td>
```

Comment: so use a class....

Comment: I have other fields that i do not want included in this total. I tried to get it to use the Id but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: So put a class on the inputs you want.... `class="form-control qty1"`

Comment: Do i change the getElementByName('qty') to getElementByClass('form-control qty1') ?

Comment: Did you attempt it?

Comment: I did. It didn't work. (I changed the script to the above and added qty1 to the class "" )

Comment: Well it is not getElementByClass but [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Most developers would use querySelectorAll instead

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I am self taught so i dont know where to start on query's